# How to write tagx (JSPX tag libraries without java)

Tags: java, templates, taglib, jspx, tagx

I can't find good documentation on how to write modern tag libraries without Java in JSPX?

Spring Roo provides lots of examples (and seems to be only project that uses tagx extensively).

I may make this another question but every time I want to not repeat myself in JSPX (DRY) I feel like have to sacrifice valuable time and go create a tag library because there are no inline macros.

I feel like I must be missing something in JSP/X.

Comment: Can you give a specific example that you want to improve using tag files or is the problem just having to create a separate file?

Comment: Basically I want to create powerful macros like you can in Velocity or Freemarker. Especially like freemarker where you can control the contents placed inside your macro e.g. <mymacro>contents</mymacro>. And yeah I wouldn't mind being able to inline the macro like you can with every other templating language.

Answer (score 3):

The best resource I could find on JSP Tag libraries is from the horses mouth:
http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html

You have to mentally convert the JSP code to JSPX.

Comment: I love when some one -1 with out a commet/reason. There is nothing wrong with answering your own questions. If there is a better alternative mr. -1 please post an answer. I assume they probably wanted to -1 the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying the same technology now.
I've found this tutorial which explains the question using an understandable example: [Spring MVC: from JSP and Tiles to Thymeleaf](http://spring.io/blog/2012/10/30/spring-mvc-from-jsp-and-tiles-to-thymeleaf)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on your question searching for something different.

I wrote a post about it at http://stories.stefanocazzola.it/2012/07/placing-your-custom-tags-inside-jar.html

Stefano